# How do I examine the execution of a software tool?

Tags: debugging

I am using GNU Screen inside Termux, a terminal emulator for Android.

I noticed that I cannot scroll up in a terminal with my finger (and I don't know any other ways) when I am inside Screen.

Instead of posting to forums or even reading documentation, I would like to try to see step by step the execution of the entire system so I can try to see myself what has happened. For example, in this case, what command was being triggered by my finger pressing the screen beforehand, and now where is that signal being sent (so as not to trigger the scrolling command)?

What would be the most universal way I could see what is happening in my system, for this or any other situation? Is there some kind of internal execution log? Do they exist on multiple levels, for example, binary, assembly language, and finally operating system level?

Comment: Are you looking for the [Android Debugging Bridge (ADB)](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb)? However, this is limited to apps. If you want to intercept low-level events such as touch events, you probably have to run a patched kernel.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much. However, what about on the Linux level, i.e. since I am running Screen inside Termux? Is there some log on the Linux level?

Comment: There is the kernel ring buffer which you can view with `dmesg`. Android also has the [`logcat`](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/logcat) utility which dumps a whole bunch of system logs. It's best to view `logcat` on your computer via ADB.

Comment: Awesome, thank you, will begin to research those.